# Creative Clans Embed Script plugin equivalent?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, embed

I need to add unique JavaScript snippets to several pages on a client's WordPress site. I used to use the above-mentioned plug-in until I encountered a nasty bug.*

The thing I like(d) about Creative Clans Embed Script is that it doesn't require you to build a library of snippets in advance. You simply paste whatever code you want to append/prepend to a page into a dedicated field on the Edit Page ... page. Another advantage to this is that it completely isolates the snippet from the page content; you don't even have to reference a shortcode.

Is there an alternative that's equally simple and flexible?

* The WordPress page editor auto-saves a draft every few minutes, right? When this happens, Creative Clans Embed Script loses any snippets for that page. I've replicated the behavior in different browsers, on different computers, and on different websites. The plug-in hasn't been updated in two years.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, thanks for explaining when this bug occurs. I've had several other (vague) complaints about losing the data for this plugin, but wasn't able to replicate it. 
I've managed to solve the problem, and published a new version of the plugin in the WP repository.

The repository still says the plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years (I've already signaled that problem in the WP support forums) but it has been updated just yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [embed javascript](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embed-javascript/) says that it can handle external files or code put directly into the visual editor.